# My database isn't being updated, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**Good evening,**

I'm using the code below to update values in my MySQL database.  At run-time the code executes all the way with no errors, however, when I view the database the records aren't been affected.  Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?  Thanks.

I've recently taught myself how to use parameters, so perhaps I might be doing it wrong - don't know.

**HERE'S MY CODE:**

```
    Private Sub updateCard()
    Call encryptCard()
    Dim ConnectionString As String = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database=accounting", FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem, My.Settings.DB_Port, My.Settings.DB_UserID, My.Settings.DB_Password)
    Dim myQuery As String = "UPDATE cc_master " & _
                           "SET ccType = @ccType, ccNumber = @ccNumber, ccExpireMonth = @ccExpireMonth, " & _
                           "ccExpireYear = @ccExpireYear, ccCode = @ccCode, ccAuthorizedUseStart = @ccAuthorizedUseStart, " & _
                           "ccAuthorizedUseEnd = @ccAuthorizedUseEnd, ccZipcode = @ccZipcode, dateModified = @dateModified, modifiedBy = @modifiedBy " & _
                           "WHERE ccID = @ccID"

    Using dbConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using dbComm As New MySqlCommand()
            With dbComm
                .Connection = dbConn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = myQuery
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccID", ListViewCard.SelectedItems(0).ToString)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccType", ComboBoxCardType.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccNumber", encryptedCard)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccExpireMonth", TextBoxExpireMonth.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccExpireYear", TextBoxExpireYear.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccCode", TextBoxCVV2.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccAuthorizedUseStart", Format(DateTimePickerStartDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccAuthorizedUseEnd", Format(DateTimePickerEndDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccZipcode", TextBoxZipCode.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateModified", Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@modifiedBy", FormLogin.TextBoxUsername.Text)
            End With

            Try
                dbConn.Open()
                dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Card info SUCCESSFULLY updated!")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                                    vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you check that `ListViewCard.SelectedItems(0).ToString()` produces a ccID that exists in your `cc_master` table? I would also create a parameter for that.

Comment: Why do you use query parameters for all the update values, but not the where condition? **You need to parameterize that too!**

Comment: Thanks, yet I did verify that and ccID does exist.  In fact, the data in the Listview is pulled from the database.

Comment: I've parametized ccID as suggested and debugged, but DB still remains unchanged.  Updated the question with the new code - hope I did it right.

Comment: My guess would be that your code does not work - which is why the database is not updated! StackOverflow!=Debugging Service

Comment: (Hmm, is it *really* allowed to store the CCV code?)

Answer (score 3):

try change `dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery()` to become:

```
Try 
   Dim affectedRow As Integer
   dbConn.Open() 
   affectedRow = dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery() 
   if affectedRow > 0 then
       MessageBox.Show("Card info SUCCESSFULLY updated!") 
   else
       MessageBox.Show("No data to be updated!") 
   End If
Catch ex As Exception
   ....
   ....
End Try
```

That will tell you how many rows were supposedly updated.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I follow.  Do you want me to simply replace that entire line with what you've suggested?

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested and the else statement was evaluated.  Which means something's wrong in my code so no rows are being affected.  Back to the drawing board.......

Answer (score 0):

**Good morning,**

After several hours of debugging and some assistance from Brandon at www.bpforums.com, the following solution was found.  The query now executes properly and the DB is affected accordingly.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Bradon @ bpforums.com pointed out to me that the DataType in my DB for ccID was INT - as such, I needed to convert the value of the listview selecteditem to an integer.  I then realized that I needed to call the *.text* instead of *.ToString* to get the actual text value of the index before I could convert to integer.

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccID", CInt(ListViewCard.SelectedItems(0).Text))
```

Thanks @habibillah, @Laurence, and @Adrian Cornish.  You pointed me in the right direction.